# Automate ffmpeg Command on all files inside directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell

i want to Automate ffmpeg Using Powershell so i can Change the Container inside my E:\My AVI Files
to MKV and output to E:\My MKV files
using the ffmpeg Command below

```
ffmpeg -i test_1.avi -map 0 -map -0:s? -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -ac 2 -b:a 640k "E:\My MKV files\test_1.mkv"
```

Comment: Hello. So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert more that just the one hardcoded file, you need to loop over the files in the sourcefolder `E:\My AVI Files`

```
$destination = 'E:\My MKV Files'    # the path for output
Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\My AVI Files' -Filter '*.avi' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $target = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath ([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, '.mkv'))
    ffmpeg -i "$($_.FullName)" -map 0 -map -0:s? -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -ac 2 -b:a 640k "$target"
}
```

<sup>Note that I didn't check if the ffmpeg command itself is correct</sup>